# How can i release the entries object

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

```
- (id)init {
    if (self == [super init]) {
        entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"qanda" ofType:@"db"];
        sqlite3 *database = NULL;

        if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_exec(database, "select * from qanda order by question", LoadEntriesCallback, entries, NULL);
        }

        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    return self;
}
```

leak near entries object: instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of [ super of self[init ...]]

leak near self: returning  while 'self' is not set to the result of [ super of self[init ...]]

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem (the tick next to the answer) as this will improve your reputation and the reputation of the person answering.

Answer (score 1):

You should have

```
self = [super init];
```

not

```
self == [super init];
```

The most common pattern to use is:

```
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Initialisation code
}
return self;
```

In your example you are not assigning the result of [super init] to anything and it is left hanging, hence the leak and the message.

If you want to release entries as per the question in you title:

```
entries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or

```
entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and

```
[entries release];
```

Before the `return` or in your `dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can release entries by replacing :

```
entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

with :

```
entries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

But i think the question should be : is this a good way of getting the contents from the db and frankly i think your code would be better if you moved the reading content from the db part to a `loadData` method.

Comment: if i release bu auto release the app is crashing actually the memory leak error is instance variable used while self is not set to the result of [[(super or self)] init ...];

Comment: in the `init` method you should use `self.entries`

Comment: sorry to interpret u on which line i have to say self.entries

Comment: `self.entries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];`

Answer (score 0):

You should autorelease it while creating.

```
entries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: thank u if i release by auto release the app is crashing actually the memory leak error is instance variable used while self is not set to the result of [[(super or self)] init ...]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

with

```
self.entries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
```

and replacing

```
sqlite3_exec(database, "select * from qanda order by question", LoadEntriesCallback, entries, NULL);
```

with

```
sqlite3_exec(database, "select * from qanda order by question", LoadEntriesCallback, self.entries, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank u very much. now near entries the leak was released. but last line return self it is giving leak as returning self which is not set to the result of '[(super of self) init...]';